# Find an injective function that maps $\mathbb{R} \to (-\infty, 0]$

Tags: functions

I'm looking for any ideas as to a function which maps $\mathbb{R} \to (-\infty, 0]$.

I considered $-|x|$ but realised that is not injective.

Comment: Could you please clarify: Are you looking for 1. A _surjective_ (onto) function, or just a mapping whose codomain is $(-\infty, 0]$, in which case $0$ need not be a value, or 2. A _continuous_ function? (If $f:(-\infty, \infty) \to (-\infty, 0]$ is injective, you can't have both continuous and onto, though you _can_ get either one alone.)

Comment: This is part of a larger problem, I'm to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ has the same cardinality as  $(-\infty, 0]$. I intend to use the Schröder-Bernstein Theorem and find an injection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(-\infty, 0]$ and then injection on the way back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exponential function $e^x$ maps $\mathbb{R}$ injectively into $(0, \infty)$.  Can you adjust this function in some way?

Comment: I didn't even think of that! Well I could take the negative of it, but that would still not include 0 in the co-domain.

Comment: @EkalAnwa You want an injection, not necessarily a bijection.

Comment: It does not equal 0 ever, and so the function does not map the real numbers to the negative real numbers including 0.

Comment: @EkalAnwa It looks like you want a bijection. Then use $f(x)=-e^x$ on $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}$ and map $\mathbb{N}=\{1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$ to $ \{0\} \cup \{ f(n) : n=1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$.

Comment: I see the error in my ways. By using $-e^x$ everything in the domain is mapped to the co-domain. It does not need to include 0, that is just what the co-domain contains, is this correct? Apologies for sounding crazy.

Comment: I quite honestly do not see the point of phrasing the question as a "hint" in this way when all is left to do is to multiply by $-1$. "What is $3 \times 7$? HINT: It is a two-digits number whose first digit is $2$ and second digit is $1$."

Comment: in my experience, what I think of as an answer could very well be a vague hint to someone else.  in any case, I was not sure if OP wanted an injection or a bijection, in which case there is still some work to be done.

Answer (score 2):

Also very handy for such kind of questions is the function $x\mapsto\arctan x$. It maps $\mathbf R$ injectively into the open interval $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$. Left composing with $x\mapsto ax+b$, for some real numbers $a$ and $b$ with $a\neq0$, allows you to map $\mathbf R$ injectively into whatever small subset of $\mathbf R$ that contains an open interval!